# Power Query Windows authentication with Odata feed

Tags: odata, powerquery

I am currently trying to find a way for a customer to connect with Power Query (plugin for Excel) to access their published Odata-feed (which is hosted by Microsoft NAV 2013 R2).

For security reasons the NAV server is set to only accept Windows as an credential type. This means that the current user credentials on the client is passed on to the webservice.

**The problem:** The users of the system is often off site and working on another domain with a VPN connection to the NAV-environment. With that said Power Query does not pass the "correct" AD-information to the published Odata-feed which means that the user is not authorized.

I am looking for a way to change which AD-credentials that are sent thru Power Query and then to the Odata webservice.

The users have no problem typing in the webservice adress in a web browser and type in the Windows credentials when prompted and access the feed. But in Power Query there is no option for typing in custom Windows Credentials when refreshing the data.

I've tried with WebAPIKey and Basic authentication. But since the NAV-server/Webservice is set to only accept Windows authentication I'm in the dark..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I got this answer from Curt Hagenlocher (Moderator on Technet)

> I'm afraid this isn't something we currently support, though we have
>   considered implementing it. We do loosely track feature requests and
>   use them to prioritize future work.

(https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03c529ba-5f20-4bc1-84de-35cc91e7c1a6/power-query-custom-windows-credentials-authentication-with-odata-feeds?forum=powerquery)